# http post and then re-direct to link

Tags: javascript, html, post, http-post, redirect

I want to have post based login and then re-direct to the same site.
this is in order to automate the loading of a web page on a raspberry pi driven display.

I started out with this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=URL TO SITE" />
```

so the re-direction works.

Now I want the http post:

```
<form action="URL TO SITE" method="POST">
  <input username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD">
</form>
```

but it doesn't work.
tested on chrome, chromium, midori.
All have the same issue.

Ideas ?

this is not for phishing, I want to automate a job inside our intranet where a raspberry pi boots and starts chromium, and logs into icinga to display metrics from our production environment.
Problem is, raspbian crashes once a week and I have to ssh to the machine to perform this manually often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<input username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD">
```

to

```
<input type='text' name='username' value="USERNAME" />
<input type="password" value="PASSWORD" name="password" />
```

and add a submit button:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Login" />
```

Then it'll work.

But, however **if you don't have access to That sites login script, Then You're doing illegal thing called [`CSRF attack`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (Cross Site Reference attack), And also a thing called [`Phishing`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing).**

So please avoid it!!

Comment: I don't think this is illegal as such, unless specified by the 3rd party site that could aswell take measures to avoid this kind of cross-site reference. But indeed I think OP is heading to a bad direction.

Comment: @Bartdude According to OP's Question I think He wants the code for phishing, See Lines: **`Login and Then redirect`** .

Comment: Yes, so what ? Indeed, it could be used for phishing, but I can think of a lot of other usages, for example if you own site1 and site2, you could use this to perform something like a "single sign-on" if a user is logged in on sitre1 and needs to access resources on site2. Cross-site requests are totally legal as such, and are not always (and actually most of the time, are not) attacks. And it's anyway up to the target site to prevent/authorize that kind of stuff !

Comment: this is not for phishing, I want to automate a job inside our intranet where a raspberry pi boots and starts chrome, and logs into icinga to display metrics from our production environment. Problem is, raspbian crashes once a week and I have to ssh to the machine to perform this manually often.